# How to remove double quotes from an echo statement

Tags: php, html, database, quotes

I have a drop down list which fetches data from the database.
But it contains double quotes. I have tried to remove the double quote using trim and preg_replace. But it did not work.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
                echo"<select name=ename[] class='mul-select' multiple value='$ename' required>";
    
                while($row=$r_set->fetch_assoc()){
    
                 $values = '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">"' . $row['name'] . '"</option>';
                 //$v=trim($values,'"');
                 //echo $v;
                   
                echo  preg_replace('/(^[\"\']|[\"\']$)/', '', $values);
                }
                echo"</select>";
    
                }
```

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP06E.png)

Comment: How about just not typing them in the first place? They're not coming from the data, you've hard coded them into your string for no apparent reason. `$values = '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';`. Voting to close the question as a typo. Always double-check your work / debug it thoroughly

Comment: @Adyson

Yes, previously my code was :
```
echo"<option value=$row[name]>$row[name]</option>";
```
However, I was having some other problems with it. Therefore, I changed it to this new code.

Comment: You need the double quotes around the value attribute, but not between the tags. I think you just need to familiarise yourself with html syntax. But my main point was that a bit of basic debugging would have made it obvious that the quote marks wasn't coming from the database at all, and then you'd have looked back at your code to see where else it could be coming from, and spotted the mistake.

Comment: @ADyson Okay thanks. I am fairly new to this. I did obviously, try to debug a dozen times before I posted the question.
And yes I know they weren't coming from the database. But within the dropdown list they were coming as I have shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes that's because they were within the option tag, right next to the output from the database. What did you do to debug? If you had echoed `$row['name']` by itself as a test, for example, you would have seen it didn't contain the quote marks, and therefore you would have known to look elsewhere in the nearby code for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//your double quotes come in this line:
$values = '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">"' . $row['name'] . '"</option>';

//change it to:                 
$values = '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
```